# Text mining using Solr and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, solr, bigdata, text-mining

I have a Solr database containing about 100m documents. I would like to text-mine these documents.

I'm thinking of making text-mining modules in javacode. And then run the jar's on a Hadoop cluster. (The output of the modules can be stored in solr.)

I'm new to Hadoop and Solr. And I would like to know, is this possible? And/Or is there a better way to text-mine the documents?

Any idea's regarding this situation, would really help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need access documents frequently?

You can use [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud) if you need to access big documents. Sharding and replicas structures can service high loading.

And json/xml stored to Solr are easily.

Comment: Yes, the documents are access frequantly. Currently there stored in a Solr cloud. This is because it needs to be possible to search all of the documents. 

But I also need to analyse /text-mine these documents. This is a cpu intensive thing to do. So therefor I was thinking of using a Hadoop cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Mahout library before you go with a completely custom code; it has a Lucene driver, and it is integrated with Hadoop for most of the purposes.
Mostly, you need terms vectors in order to do mining with Mahout. Once you have it - it's a rather seamless setup.